# How to switch to a frameset with in a frameset in selenium webdriver with java?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, frameset

Most of the answers I found were about switching to a frame within a frameset. 
Following is the Script.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to switching to `frameset`.. you can directly switch to `frame`

As your image description if your `frame` structure is like below :-

```
<frameset>
<frame name = 'frame1'></frame>
<frameset>
<frame name = 'frame2'>
<frame name = 'frame3'>
</frame>
</frame>
</frameset>
</frameset>
```

and here you want to switch frame name `frame3`.. you just switching to this frame as below :-

```
driver.switchTo().frame('frame2');
driver.switchTo().frame('frame3');
```

No need to switch `frameset`

Hope it will help you...:)

Answer (score 1):

HTML frames are used to divide your browser window into multiple sections where each section can load a separate HTML document. A collection of frames in the browser window is known as a frameset. The window is divided into frames in a similar way the tables are organized: into rows and columns.

So there is no need to Switch to Frameset you can directly switch to frame inside the frameset.

Answer (score 0):

There is class cast exception while navigating to frame within frame set in Safari browser on MAC OS.

Selenium Server: V 3.4.0
Browser : Safari V 10.10.1
OS : MAC OSX Sierra